# Installation of VirtualBox on 64-bit Windows 10: Error 2203

Tags: virtualbox

I was trying to install [Oracle VirtualBox verion 5.0.13](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) in my 64-bit Windows 10 laptop according to as many ways as I could find on the Internet but still it kept throwing this error of 2203 code: [See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkwsP.png).

I have no idea why the installation encountered the error.

I am very frustrated and really need VirtualBox for my work. Please help me to fix this installation error.

My system:
- Processor: Intel Core i5 - 3210M, 2.5GHz
- RAM: 4.00 GB
- OS: 64-bit Windows 10 Pro
- HDD: 500 GB

p/s: This is my firt time posting a question on StackOverflow. Please correct me if my question does not fit the StackOverflow rule well.

Comment: I think your question should go here:  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank @estebanrincon!